# Issue with facebook deep linking

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I am having trouble with my app deep link from facebook

I have my app link abc.net/xyz/xyz123

and My intent filter will look like these.

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
            android:host="abc.net" />


        </intent-filter>
```

All I have to do is that whenever user tap on link (abc.net/app/xyz123) I want to open my application and For that I have used above intent filter.But it's not showing me any chooser dialog which provide option to open url via (browser and your app) nor opening my app directly.
It shows me share  screen whenever I tap on link (abc.net/app/xyz123).

Before using these link (abc.net/app/xyz123) my app deep linking was working fine which have link (abc.net/app)

Is there is any way or the things I am missing in above which i used.
your support will be highly appreciable.

Comment: did you check you path? /app or /xyz would be your path in the intent filter. check if that is correct with your code.

Comment: sorry my bad its abc.net/app/xyz123

Comment: It looks like you have not set up [Facebook's AppLinks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content) properly. For deep links to work properly when coming *from* the Facebook mobile app, you will have to decorate your web content with `al:...` meta data, and the convention is to use your own custom URI scheme. It is also not clear to me what you mean by "It shows me share screen whenever I tap on link". Please add a screen shot to your question illustrating that.